# Overwriting Values in an Array

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

Trying to work on this JSON/HTML generator which will display JSON data and the associated HTML elements for a user once they enter all of the corresponding data into the input fields. I know what the problem is but I can't figure out how to fix it. When I try to generate the JSON, the values from the first set of `level_2_objName`
are stored and then moved over into the next set of `level_2_objName` because the ID name of that particular input is reset to `level_2_objName + j`. You can see the console output here => [image: console output] Any ideas? I know the fix needs to happen inside of the for loop inside of `parseData()`

```js
var categoryAmount   = document.getElementById('category_amount');
var generateBtn   = document.getElementById('generate_btn');
var parseBtn    = document.getElementById('parse_btn');
var generatedInputs  = document.getElementById('generated_inputs');
var generatedJson   = document.getElementById('generated_json');
var parsedContainer  = document.getElementById('container_parsed-html');
var totalCategoryAmount = parseInt(categoryAmount.value);

// create arrays and objects that will hold the JSON data
var AllLevelsArray = [];
var level_1_name_array = [];

function createInputs() {
 var listContainer = document.createElement('div');
 listContainer.className = 'list_container';

 var level_1_label = document.createElement('h3');
 level_1_label.textContent = 'Name of level-1 category #' + (i + 1);

 var level_1_name = document.createElement('input');
 level_1_name.className = 'form-control ' + 'level_1-name' + [i] + ' level_1';
 level_1_name.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Level-1 name');

 var level_2_list_label = document.createElement('h3');
 level_2_list_label.textContent = 'How many level 2 categories for #' + (i + 1);

 var level_2_list_amount = document.createElement('input');
 level_2_list_amount.className = 'form-control ' + 'level_2_list_amount' + [i] + ' level_2';
 level_2_list_amount.setAttribute('placeholder', 'How many level 2 categories?');
 level_2_list_amount.setAttribute('id', 'level_2_list_amount' + [i])

 var level_2_gen_btn = document.createElement('button');
 level_2_gen_btn.className = 'btn btn-default level_2-btn';
 level_2_gen_btn.textContent = 'Generate level 2';

 listContainer.appendChild(level_1_label);
 listContainer.appendChild(level_1_name);
 listContainer.appendChild(level_2_list_label);
 listContainer.appendChild(level_2_list_amount);
 listContainer.appendChild(level_2_gen_btn);
 generatedInputs.appendChild(listContainer);

 level_1_name_array.push(level_1_name);

 level_2_gen_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

  for(i = 0; i < level_2_list_amount.value; i++) {
   var level_2_label = document.createElement('h4');
   level_2_label.textContent = 'Info for level 2 category #' + (i + 1);

   var level_2_name = document.createElement('input');
   level_2_name.className = 'form-control';
   level_2_name.setAttribute('id', 'level_2_name' + [i]);
   level_2_name.setAttribute('placeholder', 'level 2 name');

   var level_2_url = document.createElement('input');
   level_2_url.className = 'form-control';
   level_2_url.setAttribute('id', 'level_2_url' + [i]);
   level_2_url.setAttribute('placeholder', 'level 2 url');

   // save for after we finish storing data for level 2
   // var level_3 = document.createElement('input');
   
   listContainer.appendChild(level_2_label);
   listContainer.appendChild(level_2_name);
   listContainer.appendChild(level_2_url);
  }
  // this is for each individual level 2 generator button
  this.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
 }, false)
}

function appendInputs() {
 totalCategoryAmount = parseInt(categoryAmount.value)
 console.log(totalCategoryAmount);

 generateBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');

 for(i = 0; i < totalCategoryAmount; i++) {
  createInputs();
 }
}

function parseData() {
 for(var i = 0; i < totalCategoryAmount; i++) {
  var level_1_object = {};
  var level_2_list = [];
  
  var level_2_list_amount = document.getElementById('level_2_list_amount' + i);
  console.log(level_2_list_amount.value);

  level_1_object['level-1'] = level_1_name_array[i].value;

  for(var j = 0; j < level_2_list_amount.value; j++) {
   var level_2_objects = {};
   var level_2_objName = document.getElementById('level_2_name' + j);
   console.log(level_2_objName);
   console.log(level_2_objName.value);
   
   level_2_objects['L2-name'] = level_2_objName.value;
   level_2_list.push(level_2_objects);
   level_1_object['level-2-list'] = level_2_list;
  }

  AllLevelsArray.push(level_1_object);
 }
 console.log(AllLevelsArray);
 
 generated_json.textContent = JSON.stringify(AllLevelsArray, null, 4);
}

generateBtn.addEventListener('click', appendInputs, false);
parseBtn.addEventListener('click', parseData, false);
```

```html
<div class="container header">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img class="logo" src="img/nav-logo.png">
    <h1>Nav Generator</h1>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>How it works</h2>
    <ol>
     <li>Enter the number of level-1 categories you will need</li>
     <li>Enter the number of respective you will need for level-2 and/or level-3 categories</li>
    </ol>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 generate_container">
     <form class="form-group">
      <label>How many Level-1 Categories do you need?</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_amount" placeholder="Category Amount">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="generate_btn">Generate</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="parse_btn">Parse HTML</button>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-7" id="generated_inputs">

   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-5" id="generated_json">

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12" id="container_parsed-html">

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if anybody can help you with this question. It's realy hard to understand your problem and follow your code without any data. Can you please provide a jsfiddle, so we can test and reproduce your problem? I haven't understand your problem yet, because I'm not sure if I understand what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah of course. Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vb29zujr/1/ don't worry about putting any data inside of the "level 2 url" input field.

Comment: pretty easy: all level 2 input fields are numbered from zero. Ids have to be unique! BUT: You shouldn't use numbered ids... instead use the name or className and use arrays!

Comment: so instead of doing `level_2_name.setAttribute('id', 'level_2_name' + [i]);` Just do `level_2_name.className = 'whateverClassName';` and then store into an array?

Comment: If you really want to use IDs, they need to include both levels, so it could be `xxx1_xxx2_name` for the first level 1 category and second level 2 category.

Comment: @JoshuaK I changed that particular variable to have a classname opposed to id's with added integers and it worked!!! I feel like I tried this already and I didn't get the result I wanted but w.e it worked lol. Thank you!

Comment: @DylanNguyen to give this questian an answer, I will formulate this problem as an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the selection of the level 2 input fields. You select them over the id: `var level_2_objName = document.getElementById('level_2_name' + j);`

j starts here from zero for every level-1. An id has to be unique within the whole document. If you create two elements with the same id, it offends the html standard. All common browsers accept it, but if you select an id, it will return the first element with this id every time.

**Solution**
You don't need the id for your problem. Use css classes instead or the name attribut. A css class can be used multiple times in a document and you can select every element over it's css class. Same with the name attribute. The name attribute provides the possibility to use array notation: `nameOfElement[]`. So you don't need to number consecutively your ids (this is never a good idea and is bad coding style. If you have the need of number your ids, most of the time it points to a design problem).

Comment: Now that I think about it - adding a counter to an id name defeats the purpose of really giving something an ID. I think I just believed that was the best way to retrieve values from those inputs but instead I was actually having to do an extra step by selecting by ID and storing those values into an array when selecting by class does that for me. This was my first S.O post and was an awesome experience. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: lol so I thought I had it but didn't realize I was still getting the wrong data. The updated fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vb29zujr/2/) I feel like it's the same issue as earlier but instead I'm grabbing by classname.